# Cannot cast from source type to destination type C#

Tags: c#, generics, methods, return-type

I have the following function that should be able to return a generic value. Like so:

```
T ReturnValueMatchedType<T>(ObjectTypes t, ReturnValues v)
{
    if(t == ObjectTypes.int_type)
        return (T) Convert.ChangeType(v.IntValue, typeof(int));
    else if(t == ObjectTypes.float_type)
        return (T) Convert.ChangeType(v.FloatValue, typeof(float));
    else if(t == ObjectTypes.string_type)
        return (T) Convert.ChangeType(v.StringValue, typeof(string));
    else if(t == ObjectTypes.char_type)
        return (T) Convert.ChangeType(v.CharValue, typeof(string));
    else 
        return (T) Convert.ChangeType(null, typeof(System.Object));
}
```

I use this function in a math formula. Like so:

```
VarDetectorA.DetectedVariable.GetVariableValue().IntValue - ReturnValueMatchedType<int>(VarDetectorB.DetectedVariable.GetVariableType(), VarDetectorB.DetectedVariable.GetVariableValue());
```

Since i use a generic method i need to supply the type it should return at the beginning. (which i dont know at that time). Since my generic function wil find the correct type to return. So i just used a place holder like `<int>` But then when i run the function i get the following error:

> Cannot cast from source type to destination type

I think it has to do with the fact that i call the method with the `<int>`. But i cant use `System.Object` since that is not valid in a math operation. How do i Make my function always return the correct type.

I know this may be a bit vague, but this is kinda my first time doing something with Generics in C#. So if something isnt clear pls let me know so i can clarify!

Comment: I am confused about what you are trying to do here. Clearly, the type of the produced result value depends on the argument `ObjectTypes t` and not really on your generic type parameter `T`. So, if whatever type is represented by `ObjectTypes t` is not compatible with (i.e., convertible to) the actual type you use for `T`, then of course you get that error... (for example, if `ObjectTypes t` would indicate a string, but you use `ReturnValueMatchedType<int>` then Kaboom!)

Comment: yeah your  conculsion is exactly right, so do you have any suggestions on how to fix this? I have 0 experience with this generic thing :(

Comment: Does `VarDetectorA.DetectedVariable.GetVariableValue().IntValue - VarDetectorB.DetectedVariable.GetVariableValue().IntValue)` work? If you're already doing the check dynamically within the `IntValue` property then you can't use generics.

Comment: If your `<T>` is `string`, you could just call `.ToString()` on the produced result value to produce a string representing the result value (which should work fine as long as only primitive types are involved). But what about if the object type is `string` and you choose a numeric type (int/float) for `<T>`? In such a case, you might try parsing the string as an int/float (and don't forget the necessary error handling if the parsing fails).

Comment: @Lee Yes that works

Comment: I don't know what `ObjectTypes` is, but it sounds like the built in [enum TypeCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typecode?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: @ErikPhilips `ObjectTypes` is a custom Enum, that says what kind of type something is. It is unrelated to the enum you referenced.

Comment: If it works then why use `ReturnValueMatchedType` at all? It's just an elaborate way of performing a cast which `IntValue`, `FloatValue` etc. are already doing. Your accepted answer doesn't appear to anything useful at all since it doesn't even perform the cast and using `dynamic` just losing type information you would otherwise have.

Comment: @Lee, i guess you are totally right. But i am no expert programmer (i  am an art student, and i learned to code out of my own intrest with no prior knowledge or help) and to be completly honest i am kinda lost in my own code, so if i can fix it with a dirty fix i am all happy xD (now i think about it, i think i do need it but that is because of other code which i have not icluded here, if you want i can add all the code to the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you really dont know the type here, may be we can use the dynamic typing to achive this.
Something like

```
dynamic ReturnValueMatchedType(ObjectTypes t, ReturnValues v)
        {
            if (t == ObjectTypes.int_type)
                return Convert.ChangeType(v.IntValue, typeof(int));
            else if (t == ObjectTypes.float_type)
                return Convert.ChangeType(v.FloatValue, typeof(float));
            else if (t == ObjectTypes.string_type)
                return Convert.ChangeType(v.StringValue, typeof(string));
            else if (t == ObjectTypes.char_type)
                return Convert.ChangeType(v.CharValue, typeof(string));
            else
                return Convert.ChangeType(null, typeof(System.Object));
        }
```

Comment: Assuming `IntValue`, `FloatValue` etc. already return values with the corresponding types, then using `dynamic` here is just throwing away type information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `ObjectTypes` is, especially when it already exists in .Net as  [enum TypeCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typecode?view=netframework-4.7.2).

What I suspect you want is:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var rv = new ReturnValues
        {
            Boolean = true,
            Double = 20.1,
            String = "myString"
        };

        Console.WriteLine(ReturnValueMatchedType<bool>(rv));
        Console.WriteLine(ReturnValueMatchedType<Double>(rv));
        Console.WriteLine(ReturnValueMatchedType<string>(rv));
    }

    public class ReturnValues
    {
        public bool Boolean { get; set; }
        public Double Double { get; set; }
        public string String { get; set; }
    }

    public static T ReturnValueMatchedType<T>(ReturnValues v)
    {
      var typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T));

      switch( typeCode )
      {
        case TypeCode.Boolean:
              return (T)(object)v.Boolean;

        case TypeCode.Double:
              return (T)(object)v.Double;

        case TypeCode.String:
              return (T)(object)v.String;

        default:
            return default(T);          
      }
    }
}
```

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pTlKmE)

output

> True
>
> 20.1
>
> myString

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but the thing is that i dont know the type when i call the method. So what u suggest here : `Console.WriteLine(ReturnValueMatchedType<bool>(rv))` is impossible since i dont know if it is gonna be a bool.

Comment: How is `t` determined (your code example) then in your application?

Comment: with `t` you refer to the method parameter right? It is initialized in other classes. And the `enum` itself is public and accesible to all classes.  Hopefully this answers your question